# Setting Keyframes for bones with python

Tags: python, bones, keyframes

I'm a beginner at python so there's probably an easy answer to this.

My goal is to create a script that will set keyframes for certain bones of the selected armature.

I tried this:

`bpy.context.selected_objects[0].data.bones["pelvis"].keyframe_insert("rotation_euler",frame=1)`

but it gives me a

`TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "rotation_euler" not found`

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you in Pose mode?

Comment: Use `.pose`, not `.data`. There are three kinds of bones in Blender, Bones, EditBones, and PoseBones. You need the PoseBone.